# How to merge two dataframes with different variations of a column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that I want to merge on a same column name but the values can have different variations of a values.

Examples. Variations of a value :

| Variations |
| --- |
| USA |
| US |
| United States |
| United States of America |
| The United States of America |

And let's suppose the data frames as below:
df1 =

| country | column B |
| --- | --- |
| India | Cell 2 |
| China | Cell 4 |
| United States | Cell 2 |
| UK | Cell 4 |

df2 =

| Country | clm |
| --- | --- |
| USA | val1 |
| CH | val2 |
| IN | val3 |

Now how do I merge such that the United States is merged with USA?

I have tried DataFrame merge but it merges only on the matched values of the column name.

Is there a way to match the variations and merge the dataframes?

Comment: Austria and Australia look closer to me than USA and The United States of America. Do you have a dictionary or some kind of conversion table with all the possible variations? A rule for inferences? Or should they be inferred by culture?

Comment: I actually have all these different variations of a value in csv.

Comment: Yo could choose some of the variations as your standard and [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) all the others before the merge. Maybe you can use regex to make a many-to-one table of replacements?

Comment: If you have a dictionary or dataframe like `{'United States of America':'USA'}`, could you add an example to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You simply create a `reftable` then merge

Your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['USA', 'US', 'United States', 'FR', 'France'],
                   'val':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df

            name  val
0            USA    1
1             US    2
2  United States    3
3             FR    4
4         France    5
```

Your reftable:

```
reftable = pd.DataFrame({'name':['United States', 'US', 'USA', 'United States of America', 'The United States of America', 'France', 'FR', 'Frank'],
                         'uniqname':['us']*5+['fr']*3})
reftable
                           name uniqname
0                 United States       us
1                            US       us
2                           USA       us
3      United States of America       us
4  The United States of America       us
5                        France       fr
6                            FR       fr
7                         Frank       fr
```

Now merge:

```
new = pd.merge(df, reftable, on='name', how='left')
new

            name  val uniqname
0            USA    1       us
1             US    2       us
2  United States    3       us
3             FR    4       fr
4         France    5       fr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .count to count how many times United States is stated in the list and then make an if command to see if united stated is listed more than once in the list. Do it to all of the other options and make a final if command to check if either any of them are in the list to output the value that you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).